# Unity build apk Failure INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

I develop Unity app for Android and iOS. When I make build in Unity on `Android Platform` → `Player settings` → `Publish Settings` add keystore and pick `Key Alias`. 
After that I have been opening `Profile or debug APK` in Android Studio and when I run app I have an error

```
Installation failed with message INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl1775631111.tmp/base.apk: Attempt to get length of null array.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
```

What can be help me?

Comment: Try uninstalling the app with the same bundle identifier.

Comment: @JeanLuc I tried but this don't help me

Comment: Change the package name of your app from Unity